# onload event on IE (with a JS error) not fired

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onload

I have an issue with IE 9+. I have a complex javascript loaded async and which is supposed to make a GET request on the "onload" event.

To define the listener

```
MY.addEventListener("load", myfunction, false);

MY.addEventListener = function(sType, callback, bCapture) {
  if ( "undefined" != typeof(window.attachEvent) ) {
     return window.attachEvent("on" + sType, callback);
  }
  else if ( window.addEventListener ){
     return window.addEventListener(sType, callback, bCapture);
  }
};
```

With break points, I saw that on IE, it uses this :

```
window.attachEvent("onload", myfunction);
```

I think it's correct. It works on all of my customer's website except for one :

On this website, there is a javscript error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Can not read the property  « split » of null or undefined
```

I think this javascript error avoid the "onload" event to be fired. How can I do to detect the "onload" event even if the page has JS errors.

Do I have an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<body onload="myfunction();">` (unless you can't load it that late).

I would bet it's supported in a more universal way.

Comment: Can not do that, my customers install a js script on their code. They do not modify their code.

Comment: It most likely fails because if the conflict with jQuery.  Can you just hitch a ride by calling $(document).ready();  It will not overwrite their `Ready()` code.

Comment: My script do not use jQuery, it's pure javascript.